# Sine Fitting in MatLab and R

Tags: r, matlab, translate

I am working on translating code from MatLab into R, however I am completely new to MatLab. I am having trouble understanding how what is happening in the MatLab code and how I can translate this to R. Here is the issue:

In the code a function calls another function called @fit_sine

```
x0=[max(y),2*3.14159/360,0.01,mean(y)]; 
options = optimset('Display','off');
coeff=lsqcurvefit(@fit_sine,x0,x,y,[],[],options);
fit=coeff(1).*sind(coeff(2).*x+coeff(3))+coeff(4);
```

This is the function @fit_sine:

```
function F=fit_sine(x,xdata)
F=x(1).*sind(x(2).*xdata+x(3))+x(4);
```

However **nowhere is xdata defined.** This is the step that is confusing to me. In R there is a similar function to lsqcurvefit which is nls but I have been unable to reproduce similar results as this MatLab code.

Here is the data used for x and y:
`y =  -0.4764  -1.0880  -1.0115  -0.8586  -0.7822  -0.7058  -0.4000   0.3644   0.8231   0.7466   0.5173   0.4408`
`x =   0    30    60    90   120   150   180   210   240   270   300   330`

As well as the output of coeff:
`coeff =    0.9098    0.8974   -157.6722   -0.1853`

**EDIT:**

Solution:

```
    fp <- function(x0, x) (x0[1]*sin((x0[2]*x+x0[3])*(pi/180))+x0[4])

    library(pracma)
    coeff <- lsqcurvefit(fp, x0, x, y)

    fit=coeff$x[1]*sin((coeff$x[2]*x+coeff$x[3])*(pi/180))+coeff$x[4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fit_sine` is a user-defined function that takes two inputs: `x` and `xdata`. Just like in R, these don't need to be named the same outside the function. The `fit_sine` function is the nonlinear function used to do the least-squares curve-fitting. `lsqcurvefit` takes the inputs `(a function, x0, x, y)` plus others. From the documentation,

> lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata) starts at x0 and finds coefficients x to best fit the nonlinear function fun(x,xdata) to the data ydata (in the least-squares sense). ydata must be the same size as the vector (or matrix) F returned by fun.

In this case, whoever wrote the `fit_sine` function defined `x0` as `x` and `x` as `xdata`, presumably to match the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how this would be translated into R as well by chance?

Comment: @megmac You can define the function `fit_sine` in R the same way you'd define any function in R. I think you mentioned that `lsqcurvefit` also exists in R, so that should be pretty simple to change over.